# Kindle Fire HD not detecting in DDMS in windows 7

Tags: android, kindle-fire, adb

My kindle fire hd 7 inch not detecting in ddms, I have already done many steps to rectify this like adding 0x1949 and enabling adb in the tablet but its not detecting at all. But my kindle fire 1st generation is detecting in ddms. Please suggest something.

Comment: Solved it myself, do not look around anywhere else as i did think i will shorty solve this. Instead just go thoroughly with this link and it will be done in less than half an hour. https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/connect-adb.html